# Android, pick element from gallery and copy locally

Tags: android, kotlin, save, gallery

For my Android native application, I need to pick an image from the gallery and save it local app folder. I run the intent to open the image picker and select the image without any problem. After this the callback of registerForActivityResult is called and I get the path of the image. Now I use this code to recreate the bmp and save it locally:

```
val stream = contentResolver.openInputStream(result.data!!.data!!)
val bm = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
  val bmpSource = ImageDecoder.createSource(
      applicationContext.contentResolver,
          result.data!!.data!!
      )
  ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(
      bmpSource
  )
} else {
  MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
      contentResolver,
      result.data!!.data!!
  )
}

bm!!.saveToLocalStorage(this, "AVATAR_${mainViewModel.selectedDevice.first()!!.qrCode}.jpg")
```

```
fun Bitmap.saveToLocalStorage(context: Context, filename: String): Boolean {
    return try {
        context.openFileOutput("$filename", MODE_PRIVATE).use { stream ->
            if (!this.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream)) {
                throw IOException("Couldn't save image")
            }
            stream.close()
        }
        true
    } catch (ex: IOException) {
        false
    }
}
```

I tried this code and it works properly on my Samsung (Android 11). The same code gives me problems on a Xiaomi device with Android 10. I thought it could be a problem with the version of Android, but in another device with Android 10 it works. The problem I'm facing in the Xiaomi device is that the image stored in the local app folder is just a black image with few Kb. The problems seems in the decode of the image and not in the saving method. Why do I get this problem? What is the best solution to copy the image locally?

EDIT: I cannot simply copy the picked image in the local app folder since I have to change its size. So I should load the image in memory, then create a scaled bitmap and finally save it to local app folder.

Comment: At the moment I found a shortkey to handle this scenario and allow the correct load and save of the image. Since I use Glide inside my app, I just used this code here to let Glide create the bitmap for me:

`val bm = withContext(dispatcherProvider.io()) {Glide.with(this@MainActivity).asBitmap().load(result.data!!.data!!).submit().get()}`

But I don't know if this the proper solution.

Comment: `Now I use this code to recreate the bmp and save it locally:` Wrong approach. Dont create a bitmap first. You got an uri. You can just open an InputStream for the uri (which you already do) and open a FileOutputStream for destination path.  Then read bytes from input stream and copy to output stream. You can copy any file then.

Comment: Ok @blackapps I will try with your suggestion.. Ty. However do you know why I'm facing the problem I described?

Comment: No i dont know. Make it yourself easy and just make a copy function that copies from uri to file path. Ten code lines or less and done.

Comment: @blackapps sorry to bother you, do you have an idea how I could recreate the absolute path from the uri I get after the image is picked? I tried every possible way without success

Comment: You should not try to get a path from an uri. You can just make a simple copy function from Uri to File. Then what would you do with a file path? I know: open a FileInputStream. But you can also open an InputStream for the Uri directly. And then read from the InputStream the same way as you would do using a FileInputStream.

Comment: the problems seems to be that when I try to use the uri I get from pick intent and pass it to FileInputStream I get an error. Somewhere I found that I need to get the absolute path of the image in order to use it with FileInputStream. I'll try again. Ty

Comment: You should not pass that uri to FileInputStream!!!! Read my comment again!!

Comment: I tried, but I get a few Kb file. However I just got new requests, I cannot simply copy the file since I have to change also the dimension of the image. So I should load in memory the picked image and create a scaled bitmap in the local app folder. I tried every possible solution found on the internet without success